# Reading problems when reading data from excel file in NoraUI

Tags: noraui

I'm having this problem when I try to run a test in NoraUI, suddenly the build does not detect the last column of the Excel, (result) and displays this on console:

```
/!\ Mauvais fichier de donnée (IOException, EmptyDataFileContentException ou WrongDataFileFormatException). /!\
com.github.noraui.exception.data.WrongDataFileFormatException: /!\ La dernière colonne du fichier de données doit faire partie de '[Résultat, Result]'. /!\
    at com.github.noraui.data.excel.ExcelDataProvider.initColumns(ExcelDataProvider.java:168)
    at com.github.noraui.data.excel.InputExcelDataProvider.prepare(InputExcelDataProvider.java:39)
    at com.github.noraui.indus.MavenRunCounter.countNbCasFailuresAndSkipped(MavenRunCounter.java:252)
    at com.github.noraui.indus.MavenRunCounter.countNbCasFailuresAndSkipped(MavenRunCounter.java:94)
    at com.github.noraui.indus.MavenRunCounter.count(MavenRunCounter.java:69)
```

I'm using **NORAUI 3.2.0**. Yesterday they were working fine and today they do not work at all. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel file is broken. You have modified/deleted the results column. You can recreate a new scenario via the CLI to obtain a correct file.

Comment: THANKS! just started exploring deeper the CLI possibilities :)